# How to write a new text in the app without an update?

Tags: android, web-services

How can I take news into my app without updating the app in the Google Play Store? Like the news apps I mean.

Comment: What you would be setting up is a feed rather than hardcoding data. Hard code changes would require updates, setting up a feed using one of the many existing APIs would automatically pull the most recent data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a webserver which serves your news (via HTTP/REST for example)

Let you app download the newest news from your server